# Laravel-Eloquent-Adding record to MySQL: Building dynamic eloquent insert command, and it returns "Column Not Found" on the very first column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've rewritten this help request, and simplified what I'm attempting to minimize the number of moving parts.

I'm an experience OOP programmer, but this is my first project with LAMP, Laravel, or Eloquent.

I'm building a data import facility in Laravel-Spark.  User will provide a .csv file.  My program will determine what data has been provided based on the header (first) row of data.  From there it will insert a new row into a MySQL table and update the provided fields.

```
function ImportPositions($incomingfile)
  {
    if (($handle = fopen ( public_path () . '/ImportFiles/samplepositions.csv', 'r' )) !== FALSE) {

        $header = fgetcsv($handle, 2000, ',');
        $headercount = count($header);

        while ( ($data = fgetcsv ( $handle, 2000, ',' )) !== FALSE ) {

          $position = new Position;
          $i = 0;
          while ($i<$headercount):

              $fieldname=$header[$i];
              $fielddata=$data[$i];
              // Example:  $position->posno="12345";
              $position->$fieldname=$fielddata;

              $i++;
          endwhile;

          $position->save();
      }
        fclose ( $handle );
    }
  }
```

The code returns this error.  The field definitely exists.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'active' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `positions` (`active`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (A, 2019-11-12 03:32:50, 2019-11-12 03:32:50))
```

In an attempt to debug, this works fine:

```
$fieldname2='active';
$fielddata2='A';
$position->$fieldname2=$fielddata2; 
$position->save();
```

Next, try to prove that my derived values are valid:

```
$fieldname=$header[$i];
$fielddata=$data[$i];

$fieldname2='active';
$fielddata2='A';

dump("|".$fieldname."|".$fieldname2."|");
dd("|".$fielddata."|".$fielddata2."|");
```

returns the following, so the two sets of variables appear to be identical:

```
"|active|active|"
"|A|A|"
```

BUT:  when I substitute the derived variables for the typed variables, it fails and gives the error listed above.

```
$fieldname=$header[$i];
$fielddata=$data[$i];
$position->$fieldname=$fielddata;
$position->save();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It looks like a legitimate query, so the answer probably lies in your table definition. What fields are in your table? I am assuming here that you know that you can't dynamically create database columns on the fly.

Comment: Hello , Please Check Your Model And Please Put In Your Model Table Name As Well As Fillable Propery So It Will Be Insert Data Into Database.Thank Yoy (Happy Coding).

Comment: When I skip the scripting attempt to build the query, and just update a field and then save it "normally," it works fine.  [[   $position->active='B';   ]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:  My input file had a BOM marker, which caused a problem with the import.  It was messing up the SQL statement, even though it wasn't visible in the debugging messages that showed the script.

TO FIX:  Easy:  Open the import file in Notepad++, and check "ENCODING."  My file showed "UTF-8-BOM."  I changed it to "UTF-8" and fixed the problem.

Thanks to everyone that gave input!